# How to rename a set of pdf files using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, rename

I know that there are several posts adressing this issue already. However I can't get my little batch script to work and I am a newbie so I would be very pleased if u could help me to solve that.

I have a bunch of pdf files named with a random number and "_text" e.g. 174098_text.pdf. Now I want to rename the file such that I only have 174098.pdf left (remove _text).

Here is my latest version of my file "Rename.cmd":

```
@echo off
@setlocal
REM +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
REM ++++++++ Umbenennen von Dateien ++++++++++++++++
REM +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


REM +++ Dateinamen und Pfad ermitteln
FOR /f "delims=" %%D in ('Dir /b %Path%\*_*.pdf') do (
FOR /f "delims=_ tokens=1-2" %%I in ('%%D') do (
    ren %%D %%I.pdf
    )
)

Endlocal
```

I hope you can help me and explain me what i have done wrong. Running the code it opens all the files but dosn't rename a single one of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/F parameter is for OPENING commands and/or get the output of a command, so when you use the second for /F you are telling the CMD to execute "%%D" file, so can't work that.

You can use a FOR without parameters, or a /R parameter if you need recursively a folder.

And you don't need to start setlocal for this job

```
@echo off

FOR %%# in ("C:\Folder\*.pdf") DO (

    :: Set the "filename.extension"
    Set "File=%%~nx#"

    :: Rename it
    Call Rename "%%#" "%%FILE:_TEXT=%%"
    REM Explanation:
    REM Rename "filename_text.pdf" with "Filename(_Text=NOTHING).pdf"
    REM (That removes the "_TEXT" pattern in each filename)
)
pause&Exit
```

Remember, if you need recursive:

```
FOR /R "C:\Folder\" %%@ in (*.pdf)
```

Comment: I tried to remove the second /F and also tried to use your code and replaced the PATH and the _TEXT with the text that is actually in my filenames. However I get a syntax error. Can you check wether or not there is a typo. I don't understand how you construct the new filename

Comment: sorry was my fault, I've missed the absolute path when setting the "File" variable, check my updated answer, now that's all good.

Comment: ok great. Now it works! I have one last question. 
can u tell me how to handle ä and ö and stuff like that in the filename. I know this is bad but I didn't do it and now I have to deal with it.

Comment: Don't need substitution of chars, you can do it in a better way, you only need to activate the code page for your country with the CHCP command, for example latin alphabet codepage is "CHCP 1252", and edefault by CMD is "chcp 850", use that CHCP command at the start of the script with your desired codepage, sorry but I don't know what codepage for your country, I think your a german guy but that chars seems latin,try with "CHCP 1252",or use google to found your alphabet codepage, or try to find the special char ä inside the codepages here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964653.aspx

Comment: thanks. chcp 1252 works and yes it is a German/Latin character